# Copying contents of Word doc and paste into another

Tags: c#, ms-word, copy, paste

How do i programatically copy the contents of one word document and paste it to another word document using C#?

I basically want to copy a personal profile (which is the contents of one word doc) and then insert it into a report.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: docx or .doc? Filetype determines your options.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
object docStart = worddocpromo.Content.End - 1;
object docEnd = worddocpromo.Content.End;

object start = SubDoc.Content.Start;
object end = SubDoc.Content.End;

SubDoc.Range(ref start, ref end).Copy();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = worddocpromo.Range(ref docStart, ref docEnd);
rng.Paste();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
    Word.Application word = new Word.Application();
    word.Visible = true;
    Word.Document d1 = word.Documents.Add();
    Word.Document d2 = word.Documents.Open(@"E:\00-Word\Test.docx");
    Word.Range oRange = d2.Content;
    oRange.Copy();
d1.Content.PasteSpecial(DataType:Word.WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming docx, use the DocumentBuilder component of http://powertools.codeplex.com/

For more information, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/02/05/move-insert-delete-paragraphs-in-word-processing-documents-using-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This link should help.

[Duplicating Word document using OpenXml and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142830/duplicating-word-document-using-openxml-and-c)

Another suggestion is to creating a copy of the word file and renaming it to whatever the required name is, if that suits your soluition.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-copy

Comment: regarding the first link. thats very similar to what i have already but what bit of the code actually pastes it to the other doc

Comment: sorry about the first link, have updated it to the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access older Word documents (Word 97 etc), there are third-party libraries available which give you full control over creating and amending the documents without having Word installed on the target machine.  This is especially useful for web servers.

We have used Essential DocIO from Syncfusion successfully in the past - http://www.syncfusion.com/products/reporting-edition/docio

Otherwise, you can use the Microsoft Office Automation libraries to access older Word documents - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301659

There are quite a few things you have to be careful with when using the automation libraries since they execute Word directly on the target machine.  Running them on a web server is a big no-no.