# Copy text from word file to a new word

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, ms-word, office-interop

I am reading the text from word file and replace some text from the readed text.

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object file = path;

object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

var doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref file, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                                 ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                                 ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                                 ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
 doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();

doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();

IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
var text =data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
```

So I have text from original word file, and now I need it to pass to a new word file which not exist (New Text).

I tried

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE";
 Process.Start(startInfo);
```

This opens new word file which not saved physically in file system which is fine. But I am not sure how can pass the text value to this new file.

**Update**

After running above code I tried

```
 var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();            
 var doc = wordApp.ActiveDocument;
```

Which comes up with  ***"This command is not available because no document is open."***

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160964/copying-contents-of-word-doc-and-paste-into-another-c-sharp

Comment: @MUG4N: I seen something similar [here](http://pastebin.com/1sV8es7b), but I am not sure what is `worddocpromo`. There is no explanation

Comment: @huMptyduMpty you should rely on word interop to do this thing instead of process.start. Create a new word document, set the content, save it to another location, now open it from there using process.start or so. Dont forget to dispose the com objects properly

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using MSWord = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var application = new MSWord.Application();
            var originalDocument = application.Documents.Open(@"C:\whatever.docx");

            originalDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
            var originalText = originalDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection;

            var newDocument = new MSWord.Document();
            newDocument.Range().Text = originalText.Text;
            newDocument.SaveAs(@"C:\whateverelse.docx");

            originalDocument.Close(false);
            newDocument.Close();

            application.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple sample that copies the entire text and formatting from one Word document to a new document. In the new document, text is then replaced using Words *Find & Replace* feature:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordCopy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fileName = args[0];

            var wordApp = new Word.Application();
            wordApp.Visible = true;
            var document = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName);

            var newDocument = CopyToNewDocument(document);

            SearchAndReplaceEverywhere(newDocument, "this", "that");
        }

        static Word.Document CopyToNewDocument(Word.Document document)
        {
            document.StoryRanges[Word.WdStoryType.wdMainTextStory].Copy();

            var newDocument = document.Application.Documents.Add();
            newDocument.StoryRanges[Word.WdStoryType.wdMainTextStory].Paste();
            return newDocument;
        }

        static void SearchAndReplaceEverywhere(
            Word.Document document, string find, string replace)
        {
            foreach (Word.Range storyRange in document.StoryRanges)
            {
                var range = storyRange;
                while (range != null)
                {
                    SearchAndReplaceInStoryRange(range, find, replace);

                    if (range.ShapeRange.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (Word.Shape shape in range.ShapeRange)
                        {
                            if (shape.TextFrame.HasText != 0)
                            {
                                SearchAndReplaceInStoryRange(
                                    shape.TextFrame.TextRange, find, replace);
                            }
                        }                        
                    }
                    range = range.NextStoryRange;
                }
            }
        }

        static void SearchAndReplaceInStoryRange(
            Word.Range range, string find, string replace)
        {
            range.Find.ClearFormatting();
            range.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
            range.Find.Text = find;
            range.Find.Replacement.Text = replace;
            range.Find.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
            range.Find.Execute(Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
        }
    }
}
```