# Mixing pages in Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have 2 word documents. How to mix its pages 1 by 1 in the new one .doc?
I mean how copy page from one document to another? I need mix it.

> Doc1_page1 Doc2_page1 Doc1_page2 Doc2_page2 ...

Comment: same question as here maybe? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160964/copying-contents-of-word-doc-and-paste-into-another-c-sharp

Comment: Similar but I dont know how to get "start content" and "end content" by pages.

Comment: Getting "start content" and "end content" by pages is going to be hard, unless you can rely on element w:lastRenderedPageBreak: http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/lastRenderedPageBreak.html