# How to copy a word document content in another word document, including bookmarks?

Tags: c#, ms-word, copy

I want to copy the content of a word document to another word document, including bookmarks. How I can do that with c#?

I've tried to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.

```
Application wApp = new Application();
Documents wDocs = wApp.Documents;
Document wDocTemplate = wDocs.Open(@"source\path\source.docx", Type.Missing, true);
Range oRange = wDocTemplate.Content;
oRange.Copy();
wDocTemplate.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
Document wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add();
wDoc.Content.PasteSpecial(DataType: WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting);
wDoc.SaveAs(@"destination\path\destination.docx");
wDoc.Activate();
```

But in destination.docx there aren't the source.docx bookmarks. How I can include the source.docx bookmarks in destination.docx at the same positions?

Comment: Errrrmmm.... So, you want to copy the entire content of a Word document to a new blank one and save that? ... Why not simply save the original under a new name/path? Mission accomplished, no?

Comment: @AnasAlweish I used that code, but in my new doc there aren't the first doc bookmars. So, it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: I agree, how is what you want to achieve any different from just making a copy of the file? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, copying the entire content is no different from saving a copy of the document to a new place. You can even achieve that without Word, simply by using `System.IO.File.Copy`.

That being said, this would be one example of achieving this through Word interop, just in case you want to save only part of a document into another document (e.g. with a different range other than `Content`):

```
var wdApp=new Word.Application();
var docments = wdApp.Documents;
var doc = docments.Open(pathToSourceDoc);
var doc2 = docments.Add();
doc.Content.Copy();
doc2.Content.Paste();
doc2.SaveAs(pathToCopyDoc);
doc2.Close();
doc.Close();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc2);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(docments);
wdApp.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wdApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Open XML SDK. 
You can find the official documentation here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

Here is some code to copy a word document taken from here: [Duplicating Word document using OpenXml and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142830/duplicating-word-document-using-openxml-and-c-sharp)

```
using (var mainDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"c:\sourcedoc.docx", false))
using (var resultDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(@"c:\newdoc.docx",
  WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
  // copy parts from source document to new document
  foreach (var part in mainDoc.Parts)
    resultDoc.AddPart(part.OpenXmlPart, part.RelationshipId);
  // perform replacements in resultDoc.MainDocumentPart
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the purpose is to work with the copy, leaving the original unchanged, the optimal approach for Word is to use `Documents.Add`, specifiying the orignal as the "template" to be used for the new document. (Note: this method can work with document as well as template files.) That will create a copy of the original document in the Word application interface so that code or the user can continue working in it. No need to open the original document; no danger of making undesired changes to it.

```
Application wApp = new Application();
Documents wDocs = wApp.Documents;
Document wDoc = wDocs.Add(@"source\path\source.docx", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
Range oRange = wDoc.Content;
wDoc.SaveAs(@"destination\path\destination.docx");
wDoc.Activate();
```